# how to add text on android automatically

Tags: android, for-loop

how to add text on android automatically . ex: if i type "081339241000.100000" can it add"t."on the front and ".1927" on the back so it become "t.081339241000.100000.1927" the "t." And ".1927" is unchanged but the middle is changeable. Can somebpdy help?

Comment: Are you looking to do this programatically, and if so have you heard of string concatenation or using `StringBuilder`?  Or, do you want this to happen from your actual Android app?

Comment: I'm fine with both if i can do that.

Comment: Any suggest to do that in easy way?

Comment: No, because I have no idea what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
String someVar = "123123123123123213213";
String.format(Locale.US,"t.%s.1927",String.valueOf(someVar));
```

try this here someVar may be any data type

Comment: Where i add that formula on? Thx btw

Comment: please post the comprehensive code

Answer (score 0):

```
  EditText edit =       (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editext1);   
TextView tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

 edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  

 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}  

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}  

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int   start, int before, int count) {  

 tview.setText("t."+s+".1927");  
 }  
});
```

}

Comment: Where do i add that formula on?

Comment: I have adewd text changed listener to observe change in edit text value and in onTextChanged callback I  am adding t. And .1927 to the entered value. You can add it anywhere after edittext deceleration. Text view can be omitted as it was for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

For Example :

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private EditText edtText1;
 private TextView txvText2;
 private Button btnDone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText1);
    txvText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvText2);
    btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txvText2.setText("t." + edtText1.getText().toString().trim() + ".1927");
        }
    });
}
}
```

It will get text from edittext and set to a textview when you click a done button.

Comment: I'm total newbie on this kinda thing but can you explain how to make that formula happen from the beginning? Thx very much for helping me

Comment: I edited code now you can try.